# ¿Select de millones de registros en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, r, select, stata

Tengo una base de datos MySQL que contiene solo cuatro tablas con información de 5 años:

1. tb_I:  20 columnas, 2,5 GB/año, 20 millones registros/año
2. tb_H: 108 columnas, 13GB/año, 20 millones registros/año
3. tb_C: 44 columnas, 13GB/año, 60 millones registros/año
4. tb_P: 107 columnas, 33GB/año, 60 millones registros/año

Todas las tablas se relacionan entre sí por las claves primarias comunes a todas ellas que son `tb_I.id` y `tb_I.ejercicio`. Tengo además definidas estas pk como indices.

El servidor de MySQL dispone de 128GB de RAM y con disco en cabina a través de una SAN de discos SSD.

La DB almacena información que es usada exclusivamente por herramientas de análisis estadístico (STATA, R).

Estas herramientas interactúan con la BD solo y exclusivamente a través de sentencias select que recuperan todos los registros que cumplen unas condiciones (ej: `select * from tb_P where ejercicio >= 2019`), **no se calculan indicadores o métricas.

Una vez que un usuario lee todos los registros con su herramienta de análisis (millones de registros con todas las variables), estos son tratados desde esta herramienta.**

Se me plantea el siguiente problema, a pesar de ser consultas muy sencillas (soy consciente de la cantidad de registros que recuperan) estas son muy lentas, del orden de 10 a 30 minutos cada una dependiendo de la tabla que seleccione.

Cuando estas mismas herramientas de análisis leen los datos directamente de sus ficheros propietarios, los tiempos no superan los 3 minutos en todas las consultas.

Entonces:

1. ¿Como se puede optimizar MySQL para que mejore el rendimiento y devuelva grandes cantidades de registros para consultas muy sencillas? (Menos de 5 minutos)
2. Mejoraría si en lugar de usar MySQL utilizará un DataLake (Minio) con PrestoSQL o similar de forma que las tablas fuesen objetos del DataLake.
3. Agradecería orientaciones sobre la arquitectura optima para esta forma de trabajo.

PD: Es importante no perder de vista que no se desean realizar cálculos en la BD, esa fue la razón por la que descarte el uso de un Data Warehouse u otras bases de datos por columnas (Clickhouse)

Comment: La respuesta a todo es depende... sin ver las consultas, los explain plan, como esta armado tu servidor, particiones de las tablas y otras cosas, es dificil decirte cualquier cosa. Igual, esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones.

Comment: Las consultas son las que indicaba, la idea es recuperar todos los registros (una jarta de registros) y como mucho filtrar por el ejercicio. En el caso que planteo se describen varios ejercicios pero actualmente estoy con la prueba más sencilla en la que solo tengo datos un ejercicio. Si bien a futuro el particionamiento se hará por ejercicio (no se si esto mejorará el rendimiento).
Se trata de un servidor virtual con 128GB RAM y 16 nucleos. Los discos son SSD en una SAN. 
¿que es explain plan?

Comment: Bueno.. virtualizar una DB ya es una mala idea.. pero en fin... un explain plan es el plan de ejecucion, que te dice que esta haciendo la DB... sin eso, no podes saber donde esta el cuello de botella...

Comment: Perfecto. Voy a revisar como poder hacerlo. 
Gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Una opción; es generar índices en tu BD; particularmente aquellos campos de tablas sobre los cuales se hace consulta; por ejemplo el que mencionas `select * from tb_P where` **`ejercicio`** `>= 2019`; desde luego en sentencias inner, join, etc los campos que allí se usen (claro sin abusar mucho de esto).

Comment: Coincido contigo en que una consulta del tipo **select * from tb_P where ejercicio >= 2019** necesitará disponer al menos un indice para el campo ejercicio. Lo que me resulta extraño es que actualmente solo he cargado en la DB un año, por lo que crear un indice no debería afectar a una consulta del tipo **select * from tb_P** y sin embargo los tiempos de muy altos. Es una consulta muy muy sencilla pero con la dificultad de que se deben obtener millones de registos.

Comment: Como dice @Blas seria una buena practica particionar tus tablas debido a su volumen de datos. La indexación de columnas que puedan ser utilizadas como criterios de búsqueda también ayudaría bastante a mejorar las búsquedas.

Comment: Muéstranos la consulta que estás haciendo y los índices en cada tabla y tal vez podamos encontrar alguna mejora u optimización, ahora, de todas formas, mover 20 millones de filas o más de un servidor a un cliente que lo va a consumir lleva tiempo,  incluso, aún teniendo índices adecuados, el motor puede elegir, con buen criterio, hacer una table scan, además esta el factor transporte de esos datos

Comment: El primer problema que veo es el `*`, ¿Es realmente necesario enviarle tantas columnas a la herramienta?. Parece que cada registro es muy pesado ¿Hacen análisis estadístico sobre cadenas?

Comment: Efectivamente mover 20 o más millones de registros del servidor al cliente llevará tiempo, pero busco algo razonable. Cuando la aplicación STATA lee el fichero propietario que contiene un único año desde la red tarda aproximadamente 50 segundos. Sin embargo, cuando lee el mismo ejercicio desde la BD tarda aproximadamente 10 minutos. Es demasiada diferencia.
Por otra parte, si es necesario traerse todos los registros, el usuario a posteriori crea variables dummy para cada registro en función de determinadas condiciones y aplica un modelo estadístico.

Comment: Bueno, la comparación que haces es en cierta medida injusta, ya que no estas considerando el tiempo que se demora en generar el archivo SATA.  Hay múltiples factores que pueden incidir en la performance, el primero es la consulta en sí, puede faltar un índice, es posible, sin embargo, mi experiencia me dice, que cuando hablamos de volúmenes importantes y sobre todo porcentajes altos de retorno con respecto a la cantidad total de filas de la tabla, muy probablemente el motor elija hacer una lectura secuencial, un table scan,

Comment: que  si bien es una forma lenta, por el volumen de los resultados muy probablemente el uso de índices no aporte ningun mejora sustancial. El otro tema es minimizar los datos a los que realmente necesitas, eso disminuye el volumen de información a recuperar y a trasladar por la red.  Lo del `select *` que ya te comentaron es una mala práctica.

Comment: Por otro lado, posiblemente SATA tenga algún tipo de compresión, que reduce el volumen físico a leer, lo que aporta sin duda un plus de performance, es como comparar en R la lectura de un CSV versus un archivo nativo Rds. Lo cierto es que deberías estudiar el explain plan para entender lo que ocurre con la consulta, pero de nuevo , por lo poco que sé, y siendo un poco arriesgado te diría que el "cuello de botella" está en el "traslado" de esas 20 millones de filas.  Si es así, yo pensaría en algún proceso de volcado de los datos a archivo .Rds si luego vas a trabajar en R.